# Получения сущности по вторичному ключу. Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Есть две связанные таблицы, Runner и Registration.

```
package ru.worldskills.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "runner")
public class Runner{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RunnerId")
    private int runnerId;

    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name =  "Gender", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Gender gender;

    @Column(name = "DateOfBirth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CountryCode", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Country country;
}
```

и

```
package ru.worldskills.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "registration")
public class Registration{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RegistrationId")
    private int registrationId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RunnerId")
    private Runner runner;

    @Column(name = "RegistrationDateTime")
    private Date registrationDateTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RaceKitOptionId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private RaceKitOption raceKitOption;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RegistrationStatusId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private RegistrationStatus registrationStatus;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private BigDecimal cost;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CharityId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private Charity charity;

    @Column(name = "SponsorshipTarget")
    private BigDecimal sponsorshipTarget;
}
```

Нужно получить строку из Registration по RunnerID.
В нативном SQL это делается легко, а тут не получается. Можно и CriteriaAPI и JPQL использовать.

Comment: А что не получается? session.createQuery("from Registration r where r.runner.RunnerId = 5 ").list()

Comment: @Orthodox, все правильно, спасибо. Я проверял по объекту бегуна, не знал что так можно.

Answer (score 0):

Например, получим регистрацию с id=5:

```
// start a transaction
transaction = session.beginTransaction();

// get an registration object
Registration registration = session.get(Registration.class, 5);

// commit transaction
transaction.commit();

System.out.println(registration.getRunner()); // получили также и runner внутри
```

Или что-то другое имелось в виду?

Comment: У вас идёт поиск по первичному ключу. Это не то, ответ дан в комментариях к посту.

Comment: Вы же говорили, что native sql не интересен. В комментах то же самое, получаем лист из 1 элемента, если такой из есть. Тоже поиск по ид, а т.к. связь 1-1, то получим 0 или 1 строку.

Comment: Там не нативный запрос, это JPQL. Я так уже пробовал, но что-то шло не так. Проблема решилась простым даунгрейдом hibernate с alpha версии на последний релиз.